# Why can't a variable which previously referred to "None" be modified?

Tags: python, function, parameters, nonetype

For example,

```
def function(data=None):
    print(data,id(data))
    if data is None:
        data=[]
    print(data,id(data))

    data.append(1)
    print("==================")

function()
function()

>> None 1781798096
[] 1780266168520
==================
None 1781798096
[] 1780266174856
==================
```

At the first execution of `function()`, variable `data` refers to a "None" object(id:1781798096) By third line of the code, now `data` refers to an empty list object(id:1780266168520) At second execution of `function`, `data` is expected to have the id value 1780266168520. But surprisingly, it gives out 1781798096 which is the same value when `data` referred to the "None" object.

But if we change default parameter to some arbitrary list, say [0],

```
[0] 1780266149960
[0] 1780266149960
==================
[0, 1] 1780266149960
[0, 1] 1780266149960
==================
```

we find out that it gives identical id values.

So my question is why can't we modify a variable which previously referred to "None" object and why does such difference occur if we set default parameter to "None" and [0]?

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Are you asking why local variables don't keep their values across function calls?

Comment: @melpomene if you change default parameter to some arbitrary list, you will find out that the id values are exactly same. Why does such difference occur when you set default parameter to "None"?

Comment: I don't understand what you're talking about.

Comment: `data` is a local variable that remains in scope only for a _single_ function call; it is not remembered from any previous function calls. Remember that `id(None)` will always return the same ID for the entire Python session, and any variable that is assigned to `None` will also have that same ID.

Comment: If you use `[0]` as the default, `if data is None` is never true, so you never assign anything else to `data`. Thus `data` always refers to the same object.

Comment: You're getting confused because you're using a list as a default function argument, which is a bit of a special case in Python. In this case the list object is the _same_ across multiple function calls! See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument. A better demo for you would be to have a default argument as e.g. a string, which will result in a new object each function call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're asking why `data`'s `id` value is the same initially, then that's because the default argument is initialised once when the function is defined, and remains throughout the program. That's also the reason for the ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument).

When `data` is reassigned, all that happens is that it points to a new object (the empty list), and this object may or may not have the same `id` (REPL sessions frequently reuse the same `ids` of garbage collected variables).

Comment: When `data` is reassigned, it points to a new object([]). So I guess `data` no longer points to 'None', isn't it?

Comment: @Jin You're right, it points to a different `[]` after each assignment.

Comment: @COLDSPEED then if it points to [], not to "None", why does `data`'s id value is the same as id value of "None"  after second execution of `function`?

Comment: @Jin Because `data is not None`, so `data` is not reassigned, so all you do is append to the same list. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument

Answer (score 0):

None is a singleton object, so you should not create multiple object of NoneType. (Note that, you can create multiple object of singleton class). In python you don't always mutate the value which it holds, you call method on object, modify it or create new object and assign reference to the variable. Previously it was holding the reference to None object, when you changed it, its holding reference to other object. Same when you again assigned None , python initialized reference value with reference of None.

Answer (score 0):

You call function with no argument, so the it is set to `None` when entering `function()`. 
When you want to retain values of `data`, you need to return the `data` variable and then pass it to `function()` in the second call.